# Is it possible to pre-fill fields in revolut.me?

Tags: forms

The “Pay me” Revolut page, available at `https://revolut.me/<username>` has fields for currency, amount and note. Is it possible to pre-fill these, perhaps with query string params? I've tried https://revolut.me/vrana?amount=100&comment=Adminer (which are the values of `name` attributes of the fields) but with no luck. I even tried POSTing these fields to the form from an external page resulting in *405 Not Allowed*.

Answer (score 5):

This works perfectly
Example link

https://revolut.me/token83827277261/eur5/comment_goes_here

Domain / username/ currency amount/comment

(Note:Without any space )

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Revolut Business links which redirect to https://business.revolut.com/revolutme/USERNAME

Comment: Unfortunately, revolut business requires api connection. U have to see the revolut documentation

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the long version of the link does not work on smartphone with Revolut app installed. If I click on a link in a web browser, e-mail client or other apps (the Revolut app tries to launch but immediately disappears).

Only if the link is copied and pasted into the web browser directly. It's a pity, it can confuse users that the link is broken.
`https://revolut.me/<username>/<currency><amount>/<note>`

The short version works fine through the app as well.
`https://revolut.me/<username>`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you can pre-fill currency and note via URL.

It looks like this: https://revolut.me/username/usd/your_note

Didn't find any way to pre-fill amount.

Comment: https://revolut.me/username/usd50/your_note